# ^C character after copying and pasting text from photoshop

Tags: html, special-characters

Our designers provide HTML for our email marketing and often, I'll see a ^C character in it when viewed in **vi**. These are invisible in textmate.

It looks something like this

```
<td width="340" align="center">Odyssey T-shirt / ^C<br>&pound;000</td>
```

I want to write a **sed** script which finds and replaces these, but how can I search for this?

Comment: Do you have a file that you can upload for us to check... I guess the charcode is somewhere between &#9786; and &#9835; but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all occurences in the file using:

```
cat YOURFILE.html | sed 's/^C/YOURSTRING/g'
```

To type in ^C hit Ctrl-V and then Ctrl-C. Replace YOURSTRING with the string you want to replace and YOURFILE with the filename.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :) I didn't know about the Ctrl-V trick